# How can a folder on windows Sync to AWS S3 when ever a new file or folder created inside

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

My purpose is to keep a local folder inside my computer synced with an AWS S3 bucket. I need to establish this from a windows server where AWS CLI installed.

Answer (score 6):

The right solution depends on how fast you need the bucket to be synced with your local folder.

A very simple solution is to use the Windows task scheduler with the batch "aws s3 sync s3://mybucket/dir localdir" triggered on a regular basis.

Answer (score 2):

You can sync your window drive and S3 bucket in sync with AWS CLI command aws s3 sync

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html